# Handle Pyramid HTTP error messages in Javascript

Tags: python, angularjs, pyramid

I'm sure there must be an easy solution for this, but I have been unable to find it. I'm using Python Pyramid in my server and handling requests/responses with AngularJS in Javascript. I'm using the Pyramid HTTP errors to handle some cases, and I'm able to catch them using the Angular `http.error()` statement.

But this is where I'm stuck, I want to do something with the error messages but if I log the response I just see html code.

In Pyramid this is happening:

```
if exists:
    # continue execution
else:
    return HTTPNotFound("The object does not exist")
```

And in Angular:

```
$http.get(url)
.success(function(data) {
    // do something
})
.error(function(data){
   // do something with the error message
});
```

How would I get that specific error message from the HTTP error? (I'm using JSON as my renderer btw)

Comment: I noticed now that all the HTTP error responses are in html and contain "Debug toolbar", could the Pyramid debug toolbar have something to do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render is not considered if you do not return a value for renderer but return a response or exception - so do not expect json on the output unless your error handler supports that.

You can do something like this instead:

```
return HTTPUnprocessableEntity(body=json.dumps(yourobj/string))
```

And then you can retrieve the JSON in your error handler and use angular.fromJson() to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but this might interest other users of Angular:
Simply call a modal to get a pop-up of the Pyramid HTML error:

```
function(error)
    {  console.log("error is: " + error);
       var modalInstance = $uibModal.open(
          {
             template: error,
             size:'lg' 
          });
    }
```

(do not forget to include $uibModal).
Very useful for debugging purposes, but not recommended for production.